# NodeJs me da este error al iniciar

Tags: nodejs, telegram

Soy nuevo en **Nodejs** y descargue este código y no lo puedo iniciar, ya estuve trabajando con otros proyectos y funcionan bien (instale el express y el cli, ademas del node-telegram-bot-api como dice en gitHub) que me puede faltar?
el código esta en el repositorio: https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes todos los archivos ?

Comment: Tengo estos:

.editorconfig
.gitignore
.travis.yml
 gulpfile.js
 index.js
jsdoc.conf.json
LICENSE
 package.json
 README.md    Mas los directorios test, lib, examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ademas de npm start debes colocar el nombre del archivo .js que quieres arrancar, ej: npm start app.js

Answer (score 3):

El comando:

```
npm start
```

busca en package.json un script con el nombre "start" para ejecutar la acción asociada. En esta caso, package.json no contiene una definición de "start" y por eso te da ese error.

Parece que el proyecto que quieres usar es una librería para ser usada desde otro programa, y no se puede ejecutar por si solo.

Answer (score 3):

Como bien dicen tienes varias formas, las comentadas arriba y otra más. Voy a hacer una pequeña guía para instalar el software, comprobar las versiones y ejecutar un script.

## INSTALANDO NODE Y NPM

Ten en cuenta que para que funcione un script que usa librerías de npm tienes que tener:

- [node](https://nodejs.org/) instalado.
- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) instalado.

## COMPROBAR LAS VERSIONES DE NODE Y NPM

Una vez instalado, podemos comprobar la versión que tenemos:

De node:

```
node -v
```

De npm:

```
npm -v
```

Por ejemplo, yo tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## EJECUTAR SCRIPT DE NODEJS

Hay 3 formas de ejecutar un script de node vía terminal.

**1.** Ejecutar vía npm start diciendole qué fichero:

```
npm start index.js
```

**2.** Definir en el fichero `package.json` el campo `script`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```

Y ejecutar con:

```
npm start
```

**3.** Ejecutar el script vía el comando node:

```
node fichero.js
```

Concretamente, en el caso de la API de yagop sería:

```
node index.js
```